# I have some some random generated arrays: how can I print just the unique ones?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code which randomly generates arrays of different lenghts (but with specific items according to my needs).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MarketBasketGeneratorAnon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] elements = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
            final String[] array = generateRandomArrayFromElements(elements);
            Arrays.sort(array);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }

    private static String[] generateRandomArrayFromElements(String[] elements) {
        int size = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, elements.length) + 1;
        String[] array = new String[size];
        ArrayList<Integer> usedIndices = new ArrayList<>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int randomIndex = getUniqueRandomIndex(usedIndices, size);
            usedIndices.add(randomIndex);
            array[i] = elements[randomIndex];
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static int getUniqueRandomIndex(ArrayList<Integer> usedIndices, int max) {
        int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, max);
        final boolean contains = usedIndices.contains(randomIndex);
        if (contains)
            randomIndex = getUniqueRandomIndex(usedIndices, max);
        return randomIndex;
    }
}
```

In this case, as you can see, I'm generating 100 arrays.

Then, I sort the elements in each array.

After sorting, of course many of these arrays become identical, having same lenght and same items in order.

I would like to print just one from each group of identical arrays, so that I get only unique arrays (no array is duplicated).

How can I edit my code to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your arrays to a `Set`: these are containers which don't permit duplicates.

Actually, you can't add arrays directly, because arrays don't implement the necessary methods such that two arrays with the same contents are considered equal (`equals` and `hashCode`); but you can wrap them in a data structure which does.

```
Set<List<String>> seenAlready = new HashSet<>();
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
  final String[] array = generateRandomArrayFromElements(elements);
  Arrays.sort(array);
  if (seenAlready.add(Arrays.asList(array)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
  }
}
```

`Set.add` returns `true` if the parameter is not already in the set. As such, this will print the array only if it wasn't already in the `seenAlready` set; and it adds the list representation of the array to the set so it won't be printed again.

Comment: This is working, but I made a mistake posting the wrong code. I wanted to use integer arrays not string arrays.

Regardless, I'll choose this as accepted answer.

I'm going to create a new question with arrays made of integers because I can't tweak the code to make it work with them.

Comment: It will work exactly the same with `Integer`; it won't work with `int`.

Comment: You're right. 

However my initial code has a bug somewhere. 

It just generates arrays too similar too each other.

They all look the same! This output for example:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

I'm never getting arrays like:

[3,4,8,9]
[2,3,6,7,8]

Everytime they start with [1,2,3]! I don't get it!

Comment: The easiest way to pick n random items from a list is to shuffle the list using `Collections.shuffle` and take the first n items using `new ArrayList<>(shuffled.subList(0, n))`.